# How to schedule a task in alternative timings in android studio(like after 50 sec then 100 sec then 50 then 100 and so on)

Tags: java, android

I have codes for repeating a task in intervals, but I want to know the codes for repeating tasks in alternative intervals (like first 50 sec then after 100 sec after that 50 sec then after 100 sec and so on)

[codes for repeating task in any interval

This code is on 'on create method' in MainActivity.java

```
    prepareAd();

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Log.i("Hello", "World");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                    }
                    prepareAd();

                }
            });
        }

    }, 55, 285,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


    public void prepareAd() {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```

}

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xayon.png)

Will I have to make changes in my codes or do I have to write fresh codes for that.Please suggest the codes for that.Thanks

Comment: You should post your code as text.

Comment: Posted the codes.